# Android RxJava and Realm - does RxJava Error Handling will catch error that occurred from Realm?

Tags: android, error-handling, realm, try-catch, rx-java

**My Questions**

1. Does RX Java error handling will automatically catch error occurred during the Realm processing its function?
2. Is RX Java error handling is better and should be replacing the try-catch exception error handling?
3. Based on my implementation below, Should I remove the Try-Catch Error Handling  of Realm implementation and Just solely rely on RXJava Error Handling?

**RxJava Implementation**

```
override fun getData(context: Context, id: String) {

        getDataObservable(context, id)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(object : Observer<String>
                {
                    override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable)
                    {
                    }

                    override fun onNext(value: String)
                    {
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable)
                    {
                        //  RXJava Error Handling here
                    }

                    override fun onComplete()
                    {
                    }
                })
    }

    fun getDataObservable(context: Context, id: String): Observable<String>
    {
        return Observable.defer(object : Callable<ObservableSource<out String>>
        {
            @Throws(Exception::class)
            override fun call(): Observable<String>
            {
                return Observable.just(realmModel.getDataRealm(context,id))
            }
        })
    }
```

**Realm Implementation**

```
override fun getDataRealm(context: Context, id: String): String {

    var realm: Realm? = null

    var storeData:String? = null;

    try {
        Realm.init(context)

        val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("database.realm")
                .build()

        realm = Realm.getInstance(config)

        realm!!.executeTransaction {

            val getData = realm.where(database::class.java).equalTo("dataID",id).findAll()      
            storeData = getData.dataName
        }

        realm.close()

        return storeData

    }catch(e:Exception) {

        realm?.close()  // Realm Try-Catch Error Handling

    }finally {
        realm?.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know the current status of realm but for me it was a lot of work to combine Realm and RxJava, especially the async calls as the async thread from Rx does not work well with the one from Realm, or the other way round.

Comment: Technically Realm works just fine on multiple threads as long as you get a thread-local instance for the thread you're working on with `Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->`. So it's not hard, you just have to know what you're doing.

Comment: btw you should use `.subscribeWith(DisposableObserver<`

Comment: @epicpandaforce I quite new to RXJava and Realm, I will look into your advice and try to understand ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have continue to proceed the implementation above and remove the `try-catch` for the Realm Implementation, I purposely trigger an Error and Seem like RXJava can catch the error occurred from Realm at the `onError`

**I personally would conclude that:**

1. Yes, RX Java error handling will automatically catch error that occurred during the Realm processing its function.
2. So far for my case, RX Java could handle the catch error, so for my own convenience, I would choose RX Java error handling over Realm try-catch exception error handling.
3. Since I using RX Java error handling, I think there Realm try-catch error handling is not necessary anymore.